# Is function overloading in a namespace (compared to a class with static members) a bad idea?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

This is a question about an idea rather a real code

In the past I always wrote many method overloadings and it was fine:

```
class myclass
{
public:

    std::string method(type1 a)
    {
        return method(...);
    }

    std::string method(type2 a)
    {
        return ....;
    }

}
```

That was working fantastic.

The problem began from yesterday when I wrote a function overloading is a namespace:

```
namespac myspace
{

    std::string func(type1 a)
    {
        return func(...);
    }

    std::string func(type2 a)
    {
        return ....;
    }

}
```

Here, the problem is that inside the namespace, the compiler does not know the second function. So, it tries to convert the given type into something that matches the first function. Unfortunately the compiler did not tell me that it was a mistake by me. Although I sent `type2` to the function, it tried to convert it to `type1` to call itself and the result was a stackoverflow.

Even though changing the order of functions fix the problem, I wonder is using a function overloading in a namespace a bad idea in professional C++ programming?

Comment: The problem isn't with overloading the functions, but with making sure the definition you want to call is in scope when you call it.

Comment: You'd get the same error if this was outside a namespace. Classes are special (for some reason).

Comment: Ideological question, unfortunately. You will find more than a few coding standards that will advise "Do not ever overload. ***EVER***" especially in safety-critical applications where clarity and predictability are fundamental musts. No one wants a rocket to detonate a hundred feet up because `bool` happened to be a better fit.

Comment: As for the specific question, (1) regarding the real problem: in professional programming, you're generally expected to declare your functions in a header file, and define them elsewhere (usually in a .cpp file, but occasionally in the same header file) unless you don't want to expose the function.  The end result is that you don't need to worry about the order you define functions.  (2) I had one job that discouraged overloading and recommended making parameter types obvious, getUserIdByUsername(), getUserIdForAdmin() etc.  I didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

As someone commented, this problem is not about overloading function, rather, it is about the order of function declaration.

The error in your namespace is clear, when compiler see

```
std::string func(type1 a)
{
    return func(/*expect type2*/);
}
```

It must know prototype/definition of the `func(/*expect type2*/)` at that time.

However, in your class definition:

```
class myclass
{
public:

    std::string method(type1 a)
    {
        return method(/*expect type2*/); // OKAY, no problem here
    }

    std::string method(type2 a)
    {
        return ....;
    }
}
```

Compiler does not throw any error although the prototype/definition of `method(/*expect type2*/)` is not known at that location. Why?

According to this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inline_functions.htm

> A function definition in a class definition is an inline function definition, even without the use of the inline specifier.

That means, when compiler compiles `myClass`, it compiles the member **prototype** only, of course, in this example, no error. The member **definition** will be compiled later e.g. when you invoke that member. At this time, all prototype of member functions in `myClass` are completely known. Thus, compiler won't throw any error.

EDIT: namespace is namespace, class is class; they have different meaning. Choosing either namespace or class depends on your own situation rather than the desire to get rid of function order error. In your example, you can still use namespace by declaring all needed prototypes:

```
namespac myspace
{
    std::string func(type2 a); // prototype

    std::string func(type1 a)
    {
        return func(...); // fine
    }
}
```

So, the best practice is always declaring prototype before definition/calling :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One of my concerns is that should I avoid practicing using namespace where a set of functions can be wrapped in static way inside a class?